# How to know whether the image captured is from front camera or back camera when we capture picture through MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I know it's possible when we invoke `Camera` and get this info from `Camera.getCameraInfo()`, but how can we get to know which camera was used to capture the picture when we invoke camera from `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent as `onActivityResult()` returns data only as bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Camera.getCameraInfo() to determine if a camera is on the front or back of the device, and the orientation of the image.For more information go through its guidlines 
     [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Comment: I guess you didn't read my question fully, I know we can achieve that way, but what I want is when we invoke camera through `Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`

Comment: CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camNo, camInfo);
           
            if (camInfo.facing==(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)) {
                mCamera = Camera.open(camNo); //perform something if it is front camera
            } else { //back camera}

Comment: I dont think there is any other way you can check after image has been captured..You have to detect while camera is open and code accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "NO". If you get a captured Jpeg, you may (in some cases) determine the source camera by examining the EXIF headers of this file.

Comment: Which EXIF header?

Comment: EXIF headers can provide rather detailed description of the camera that was used. E.g. *Camera maker*, *Camera model*…One indicator that helps me on my no-name Chinese device is the *Focal length*. Here, this is 4mm for the "main" camera, and 2mm for the secondary lens.

Comment: that might help, but at the end of it, it's still guesswork ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯